# Linq to Sql How To delete table along with all relationships

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table "User" With a relationship to around 7 other tables. If I try to delete the user it won't let me unless I delete all the data in the other tables that has a userId. Is there a way to delete everything automatically without having to delete each one of the tables with that UserId  one table at a time?

Comment: Cascaded delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cascade delete.
Code first: In OnModelCreating method of context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>()
.HasOptional(c => c.User)
.WithMany(c => c.Table1s)
.HasForeignKey(c => c.UsereID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>()
.HasRequired(c => c.User)
.WithMany(c => c.Table2s)
.HasForeignKey(c => c.UsereID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```